# Architecture of a chatbot - how to organize and fetch possibilities?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, neural-computing

I'm building a chatbot that would respond to text messages.

Let's say that my chatbot works for customers of an internet provider and it can respond to the following things:

- Problems:

  - About payment;
  - About internet connection.
- General requests:

  - Change user's account e-mail;
  - Call for technical assistance.

My question is: what's the data structure that I could use to organize this tree?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! A reference request like yours is too broad for Stack Exchange -- you ask for a survey of a whole research area! You need to narrow your focus considerably before a question of reasonable scope appears. Try talking to your advisor(s), search with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=some+query) and check out [this guide to better (re)searches](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13594/1419) on [academia.SE].

Comment: @Raphael maybe it's less broad now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that helps!  Now: what data structures have you considered?  What approaches have you already considered and rejected, and why did you reject them?  What properties do you want the data structure to have?  You need to tell us  what (objective) criteria to use for evaluating possible answers.

Comment: @D.W. Maybe it's better to see the examples in the answer. This might answer my question about it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @juniorgarcia ah remapped the whole thing. You can organize data like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450560/how-best-to-store-data-for-a-chatbot

Comment: "what's the data structure that I could use to organize this tree" -- why, a tree? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Raphael  ok, let's change the question: What's the recommended approaches to store the data about the chatbot decisions in terms of performance and organization? Is the "default" approach of foreign keys a good approach? What's the better way that I can store the data about the intelligence of the chatbot?

Comment: "recommended" sounds subjective to me, and subjective questions don't work well here (see our [help/dont-ask]).  Instead, list what criteria you want to use to judge approaches.  What are your requirements?  What are you trying to optimize?  Then, tell us what approaches you've considered, how you think they fare on those metrics/requirements, and why you've rejected them.  Finally, if you want to modify the question, you can't do that by just leaving a comment.  You need to either edit the question (but in this case you might not want to invalidate the existing answer) or post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

When Building AI and ML for you Chatbot, you basically have 2 options:

1. You can use a 3rd party tool which will take care of the
   AI/Conversational part of the Chatbot.
2. You can make your own using Machine Learning.Overwhelming, but quite
   a few developers are choosing to go this route and many companies
   are trying to democratize Machine Learning.

You can build your own NLP(Natural Language Processing) by using Machine Learning. One of the first things to consider will be the type of model you want to build.

**Using an NLP/NLU Platforms:** Natural Language Processing (NLP) and Natural Language Understanding (NLU) platforms attempt to solve the problem by parsing language into entities, intents and a few other categories. Different NLP platforms may have different names however the essence is moreso the same.

Categories:

- **Agents** correspond to applications. Once you train and test an agent,
  you can integrate it with your app or device.
- **Entities**: represent concepts that are often specific to a domain as a
  way of mapping natural language phrases to canonical phrases that
  capture their meaning.
- **Intents** represent a mapping between what a user says and what action
  should be taken by your software.
- **Actions** correspond to the steps your application will take when
  specific intents are triggered by user inputs. An action may have
  parameters for specifying detailed information about it.
- **Contexts** are strings that represent the current context of the user
  expression. This is useful for differentiating phrases which might be
  vague and have different meaning depending on what was spoken
  previously.

NLP Platforms:

- [API](https://api.ai/)
- [WIT](https://wit.ai/)
- [LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/)
- [Microsoft Bot Connector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html)

Reference :

- [NLP & Machine Learning Tutorial](https://chatbotslife.com/ultimate-guide-to-leveraging-nlp-machine-learning-for-you-chatbot-531ff2dd870c#.ix5f14ep6)
- [Chatbot AI Tutorials](https://chatbotslife.com/tagged/how-to)
- [Machine Learning in a Year](https://medium.com/learning-new-stuff/machine-learning-in-a-year-cdb0b0ebd29c#.pci0f693e)
- [Neural Networks for Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks)
- [You Too Can Become a Machine Learning Rock Star!](https://backchannel.com/you-too-can-become-a-machine-learning-rock-star-no-phd-necessary-107a1624d96b#.n2eaafdn6)